# Make a thing like lightbow without image inside

Tags: javascript, html, css

is there any way to make a thing like lighbox but don't have pictures in it, just make like text or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists plenty of "lightboxes" which provide that feature.

Eg.: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox

You can view some examples here of one of the styles: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/ (Inline HTML, AJAX)